# cannot install rosserial in kinetic

Tags: arduino, rosserial, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried to install rosserial for kinetic.But when i try to install ros_lib into arduino environment,it gives the error message `[rospack] Error: package 'rosserial_arduino' not found` .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237307/cannot-install-rosserial-in-kinetic/) by [renjith](https://answers.ros.org/users/27201/renjith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2016-06-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vmatos](https://answers.ros.org/users/17756/vmatos/) on 2016-07-07**:
Could you explain all the steps you took?

If you downloaded the source and built the package, have you sourced `setup.bash`?

**Comment by [renjith](https://answers.ros.org/users/27201/renjith/) on 2016-07-07**:
I actually figured out the problem a while back.I didnt add the setup file to bashrc and so whenever i opened a new terminal , i got this error.Still thanks vmatos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't see any release for Kinetic of `rosserial` on [wiki/rosserial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial) or [status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=serial](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=serial), so I would think not being able to install it is expected.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0